# How to get tags of object via relation model in Django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have 3 models like this :

```
Entry:
    text = TextField(..)
    ...

Tag:
    text = CharField(..)
    ...

EntryTag
    entry = ForeignKey(Entry)
    tag = ForeignKey(Tag)
```

based on `EntryTag` objects, I want to populate any `Entry` object with `.tags` field, i.e. :

```
for e in myEntries:
    e.tags = Tag.objects.filter(?) # how do I select which tags are related to e?
```

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you haven't set custom `related_name` value for any of your FK fields:

```
Tag.objects.filter(entrytag_set__entry=e)
```

Comment: Thanks! Teşekkürler :)